# Running react application in AWS EC2 server

Tags: reactjs

I created react app using create-react-app.
I have deployed to aws.

How can I run it in production without using server like apache or nginx ?

Thank You.

Comment: Use Node.js. There is no option to run SPA without server.

Comment: I have node js. How can I give project path, for the ip address or domain name?

Comment: You should use AWS tag to reach required community. We use nginx proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [install nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/) on your EC2 instance.

Then, run `npm run build`. It will generate a `build` folder, that then should be used as nginx vhost `webroot`.

`npm run build`

> Builds the app for production to the build folder. It correctly
>   bundles React in production mode and optimizes the build for the best
>   performance.
>
> The build is minified and the filenames include the hashes. Your app
>   is ready to be deployed!

Simple as that.

Or,

> For environments using Node, the easiest way to handle this would be
>   to install serve and let it handle the rest:
>
> `npm install -g serve serve -s build`

Comment: I did this : `npm install -g serve serve -s build` . But it is running running server locally on AWS EC2, where as we want it to be global. Is there anything else which I have to do.